# How to push a script from the server, to be ran on the client?

Tags: openvpn

I have a device which I cannot connect to anymore (ssh, salt, ...), do not have an easy physical access to - but which still opens an OpenVPN session to my server. In order to try to recover it, I would like to:

- on the server force a reconnect for this client
- when the client reconnects - push a script which the client would execute (first I would have a look on what is going on via a dump of the logs and configs, and then possibly recover the correct settings)

There are solution for [scripts to be ran on the client once it connects](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28733/how-do-i-run-a-script-after-openvpn-has-connected-successfully) but all assume that this is the client's choice (= the configuration is on the client side). I am looking for the other way round.

I can see a security problem is such an approach (the VPN provider could take over the client machine), but maybe there is a way which is not obvious from the documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To force client to reconnect you can:

- drop specific source IP address and source port combination using *iptables* in *OUTPUT* chain, or destination address and destination port in *INPUT* for longer time period than ping-restart interval,
- kill specified client in OpenVPN's management interface: [see here](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/79-management-interface.html)
- restart OpenVPN service @ server, all of the above will force new symmetric key exchange, new sockets and new dst port number.

Why you can't execute a script:

- you're out of luck here. Scripts are configured and must be located at the client side, AFAIK even OpenVPN's ccd doesn't allow that, proper "pull" configuration directive is required on the client side too - to allow the server to pull the most basic tunnel options like: cipher, buffer sizes, compression, routes etc, but not the scripting configuration directives.
- <del>in default configuration OpenVPN works with nobody privileges,</del>
- this would be a security hole.